# Rapidminer extract numbers from within strings

Tags: rapidminer

What is the correct way to extract the numbers from within the nominal 'nameClust' attribute below?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way would be to first remove the cluster prefix from the Attribute. You can do this with the "Replace" Operator and a regular expression. Then you have to use the "Parse Numbers" Operator to change the value type from Nominal to Numerical.

Alternatively you can use the expression builder within the "Generate Attributes" Operator to achieve the same effect.

If you only want to extract a single cluster number, you can use "Extract Macro" and then with "Generate Macro" use the same expression builder as in the second example to get the number.

See the attached process xml for an example of all the three versions.
Also feel free to ask further, or re-post, questions in the [RapidMiner community forum](http://community.rapidminer.com).

```
<?xmlversion="1.0"encoding="UTF-8"?><processversion="7.6.001">
<context>
<input/>
<output/>
<macros/>
</context>
<operatoractivated="true"class="process"compatibility="6.0.002"expanded="true"name="Process">
<processexpanded="true">
<operatoractivated="true"class="retrieve"compatibility="7.6.001"expanded="true"height="68"name="RetrieveIris"width="90"x="45"y="136">
<parameterkey="repository_entry"value="//Samples/data/Iris"/>
</operator>
<operatoractivated="true"class="split_data"compatibility="7.6.001"expanded="true"height="103"name="SplitData"width="90"x="179"y="136">
<enumerationkey="partitions">
<parameterkey="ratio"value="0.5"/>
<parameterkey="ratio"value="0.5"/>
</enumeration>
</operator>
<operatoractivated="true"class="k_means"compatibility="7.6.001"expanded="true"height="82"name="Clustering"width="90"x="313"y="85"/>
<operatoractivated="true"class="apply_model"compatibility="7.6.001"expanded="true"height="82"name="ApplyModel"width="90"x="447"y="136">
<listkey="application_parameters"/>
</operator>
<operatoractivated="true"class="multiply"compatibility="7.6.001"expanded="true"height="124"name="Multiply"width="90"x="648"y="136"/>
<operatoractivated="true"class="extract_macro"compatibility="7.6.001"expanded="true"height="68"name="ExtractMacro"width="90"x="849"y="697">
<parameterkey="macro"value="extracted_cluster"/>
<parameterkey="macro_type"value="data_value"/>
<parameterkey="attribute_name"value="cluster"/>
<parameterkey="example_index"value="1"/>
<listkey="additional_macros"/>
</operator>
<operatoractivated="true"class="generate_macro"compatibility="7.6.001"expanded="true"height="82"name="GenerateMacro"width="90"x="1050"y="697">
<listkey="function_descriptions">
<parameterkey="cluster_number"value="replace(%{extracted_cluster},&quot;cluster_&quot;,&quot;&quot;)"/>
</list>
</operator>
<operatoractivated="true"class="generate_attributes"compatibility="7.6.001"expanded="true"height="82"name="GenerateAttributes"width="90"x="849"y="442">
<listkey="function_descriptions">
<parameterkey="parsed_cluster"value="parse(replace([cluster],&quot;cluster_&quot;,&quot;&quot;))"/>
</list>
<descriptionalign="center"color="purple"colored="true"width="126">Alternativapproachbyusingasingleexpression.</description>
</operator>
<operatoractivated="true"class="replace"compatibility="7.6.001"expanded="true"height="82"name="Replace"width="90"x="849"y="136">
<parameterkey="attribute_filter_type"value="single"/>
<parameterkey="attribute"value="cluster"/>
<parameterkey="include_special_attributes"value="true"/>
<parameterkey="replace_what"value="cluster\_"/>
<descriptionalign="center"color="purple"colored="true"width="126">Firstremovethe&amp;quot;cluster_&amp;quot;SubstringfromtheclusterAttribute.It'simportanttocheckthe&amp;quot;includespecialattributes&amp;quot;parameter</description>
</operator>
<operatoractivated="true"class="parse_numbers"compatibility="7.6.001"expanded="true"height="82"name="ParseNumbers"width="90"x="1050"y="136">
<parameterkey="attribute_filter_type"value="single"/>
<parameterkey="attribute"value="cluster"/>
<parameterkey="include_special_attributes"value="true"/>
<descriptionalign="center"color="purple"colored="true"width="126">Parsethevaluesofthe&amp;quot;clusterAttribute,tochangethevaluetypefromnominaltonumerical.</description>
</operator>
<connectfrom_op="RetrieveIris"from_port="output"to_op="SplitData"to_port="exampleset"/>
<connectfrom_op="SplitData"from_port="partition1"to_op="Clustering"to_port="exampleset"/>
<connectfrom_op="SplitData"from_port="partition2"to_op="ApplyModel"to_port="unlabelleddata"/>
<connectfrom_op="Clustering"from_port="clustermodel"to_op="ApplyModel"to_port="model"/>
<connectfrom_op="ApplyModel"from_port="labelleddata"to_op="Multiply"to_port="input"/>
<connectfrom_op="Multiply"from_port="output1"to_op="Replace"to_port="examplesetinput"/>
<connectfrom_op="Multiply"from_port="output2"to_op="GenerateAttributes"to_port="examplesetinput"/>
<connectfrom_op="Multiply"from_port="output3"to_op="ExtractMacro"to_port="exampleset"/>
<connectfrom_op="ExtractMacro"from_port="exampleset"to_op="GenerateMacro"to_port="through1"/>
<connectfrom_op="GenerateAttributes"from_port="examplesetoutput"to_port="result2"/>
<connectfrom_op="Replace"from_port="examplesetoutput"to_op="ParseNumbers"to_port="examplesetinput"/>
<connectfrom_op="ParseNumbers"from_port="examplesetoutput"to_port="result1"/>
<portSpacingport="source_input1"spacing="0"/>
<portSpacingport="sink_result1"spacing="0"/>
<portSpacingport="sink_result2"spacing="399"/>
<portSpacingport="sink_result3"spacing="0"/>
<descriptionalign="center"color="yellow"colored="false"height="347"resized="true"width="580"x="27"y="10">Splitthedataintwosubsets&lt;br/&gt;buildaclusteringmodelonthetrainingset&lt;br/&gt;andthenapplyitionthetestset</description>
</process>
</operator>
</process>
```